# Как правильно написать SQL запрос. Вроде верно написал, однако выводит лишние записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Выведите коды всех рейсов, в рамках которых воздушные судна в данный момент находятся в воздухе (статус таких рейсов — `Departed`). 
В выборку должны попасть рейсы, аэропорт назначения (`arrival`) которых `MQF` или `ABA`, а также рейсы, аэропорт отправления (`departure`) которых не `PY`J и не `CNN`. 
В выборке должен присутствовать один атрибут: `trip_code`.

Мой запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT trip_code 
FROM trips 
WHERE (
    status = 'Departed' 
    OR departure IN ('MQF', 'ABA') 
  )
  AND departure NOT IN ('PYJ', 'CNN')
```

Comment: Возможно, нужно так ``WHERE (status = 'Departed') AND( departure IN ('MQF', 'ABA') OR departure NOT IN ('PYJ', 'CNN'))``

Comment: казалось бы - отформатируй код и посмотри на скобки и будет наглядно уже видно что что-то не так.

Comment: где у вас про `arrival` вообще?

Answer (score 0):

Такой запрос должен отработать:

```
SELECT trip_code 
FROM trips
WHERE (
   (departure NOT LIKE 'PYJ' AND departure NOT LIKE  'CNN')  
    OR (arrival LIKE 'MQF' OR arrival LIKE 'ABA')
  ) 
  AND status LIKE 'Departed'
```